# PlotRange truncates data in the y direction but not in the x. Why?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here's a very bizarre inconsistency I've just struggled with and I'm wondering why it exists or if I'm missing something.

I have some noisy data and I wish to make a framed plot of the data but allow the data to extend outside the vertical limits of the frame (for stylistic reasons). Like so:

```
    xs = Range[0, 0.5, 0.005];
    data = Transpose[{xs, Sin[Pi xs]^2 + 0.05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[xs]]}];

    opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True,
       PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20];

    ListLinePlot[{}, opts,
     Prolog -> First@ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
    ]
```

[image]

However, my dataset contains points outside my desired x limits, thus my data is more accurately given by:

```
    xs = Range[-0.1, 0.6, 0.005];
    data = Transpose[{xs, Sin[Pi xs]^2 + 0.05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[xs]]}];
```

Which when plotted with exactly the same code gives:

[image]

which obviously extends in both the x and y directions when I only want the extension in the y.

My solution is to change the value of `PlotRange -> All` in the 'Prolog' 'ListLinePlot'. However, this only works in the y-direction, observe:

```
    Grid[{{
       ListLinePlot[{}, opts,
        Prolog -> First@ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 1}}]
        ],
       ListLinePlot[{}, opts,
        Prolog -> First@ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, All}]
        ],
       ListLinePlot[{}, opts,
        Prolog -> First@ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
        ]
       }}]
```

[image]

As you can see the data never obeys the PlotRange in the x direction! Looking into the content of the `First@ListLinePlot[data, ...]` we can see that the graphics items describing the data do get clipped in the y-direction:

[image]

You can see there are several instances near the beginning where the `Line`'s y-coordinate has been clipped to `0.` and many at the end where it is `1.`.

However if we try to restrict the graphics in the x-direction:

[image]

We see no such clipping occurs, leading to the problems described above.

Why is this happening? Is there an elegant workaround? My current method to circumvent this problem is to create and `Interpolation` of may data and then use `Plot` as opposed to `ListLinePlot` in the `Prolog` but this seems like overkill for what should be a simple fix?

I note that merely taking a subset of my data won't work for my real data as the x-values do not lie nicely on my coordinates, ie I might not have a value at 0 so I would be left with a gap either side.

Many thanks.

Comment: To allow the data to be plotted outside the frame. Unless I'm missing something I thought that (using `Prolog` etc) was one of the simplest ways to achieve that. `ListLinePlot[data, opts]` doesn't produce the first plot which is what I want.

Comment: @Kuba Unfortunately `PlotRangeClipping` does not allow to specify separate clipping specifications for the axes and in addition `ListLinePlot` handles this option for them inconsistently. :(

Comment: I suggest trying RegionFunction to clip the data on the x axis. No time for a full answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Good idea! `RegionFunction` is a [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) option of `ListLinePlot` (see under the "Details" field). But this option is not recognized and does not work (version 10.3.1)... :(

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov yep, I was only refering to the usage of `Prolog`, not the problem of OP.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov never mind that, I've realized, that `RegionFunction` will only handle the actual functions being plotted, not `Prolog` or `Epilog`

Answer (score 4):

I, too, could not find a simple, transparent solution, so here is a simple but not transparent solution.

```
ListLinePlot[Reverse[data, 2], PlotRange -> {All, {0, 0.5}}];
Reverse[Cases[%, Line[{z__}] -> z, Infinity], 2];
ListLinePlot[{}, opts, Prolog -> First@ListLinePlot[%, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Because `ListLinePlot` appears to treat `PlotRange` differently for the two coordinates, plot the data with the coordinates reversed, extract the `Line`, reverse the coordinates again, and plot the result.

**Addendum**

A more stringent test is to use data for which no points lie precisely at the edges of the plot in `x`.  For instance, with `xs = Range[-0.15, 0.6, 0.1];`, the plot still works properly.  (A coarse set of data is used for visual clarity.)

[image]

Approaches that, directly or indirectly, simply delete data points outside `PlotRange` would have blank space at either end of the plot.

Comment: +1 for _simple but not transparent solution_

Answer (score 1):

It is another gedanken functionality in *basic* plotting functions. Using new in version 10 `Region*` functionality here is a workaround:

```
xs = Range[0, 1, 0.005];
data = Transpose[{xs, Sin[Pi xs]^2 + 0.05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[xs]]}];

inf = 10;
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[Line[data], Rectangle[{0, -inf}, {0.5, inf}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

> [image]

With older *Mathematica* versions you could proceed in the following way:

```
Show[Plot[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 0, .5}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, All}], PlotRange -> {{0, 0.5}, {0, 1}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImagePadding -> 20, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some fake data:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-.2, .2}, 37] + (Cos[.1 #] & /@ Range[-1, 35]) // Thread[{Range[-1, 35], #}] &
```

Make a plot without the frame that clips the data in the x direction but not in the y direction (by having an extended y range):

```
plot = ListPlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Joined -> True, 
  Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ImagePadding -> None, PlotRange -> {{2, 32}, {-1.2, 1.2}}, 
  AspectRatio -> Full]
```

[image]

Apparently `AspectRatio -> Full` is very important here, but I realized that with trial and error and am too lazy to investigate further. `ListPlot` with `Joined -> True` seems to behave nicer with `Inset` and gives the same result.

Make an empty framed plot with the correct frame range (defined by `PlotRange`) and add the line as an inset:

```
Plot[{}, {x, 2, 32}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{2, 32}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> Inset[plot, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {30, 2.4}]]
```

[image]

Here's a functional form:

```
xClipListPlot[pts_List, {{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}}, 
  yRange_List: Automatic] := 
 Module[{x, 
   yR = If[yRange == 
      Automatic, {(y1 + y2)/2 - (y1 - y2)/0.4, (y1 + y2)/2 + (
       y1 - y2)/0.4}, yRange], plot},
  plot = ListPlot[pts, InterpolationOrder -> 3, Joined -> True, 
    Frame -> False, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
    ImagePadding -> None, PlotRange -> {{x1, x2}, yR}, 
    AspectRatio -> Full];
  Plot[{}, {x, x1, x2}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[plot, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {x2 - x1, First@Differences[yR]}]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `PlotRange -> s` you are only specifying the range on the y-axis.  Look at the **Details** section of the [`PlotRange` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html).  This is why only the y-axis range is being truncated.

You can use the format that specifies the range for both the x and y axis but this will make the frame cover those ranges; and you don't want that.  You can, however, use `Show` with an empty `ListLinePlot` of your desired frame range and  a second plot that takes only the points in the x-axis range.  Then make use of `PlotRangeClipping` and `ImagePadding` in `Show` to get your desired result.

```
xs = Range[-0.1, 0.6, 0.005];
data = Transpose[{xs, Sin[Pi xs]^2 + 0.05 RandomReal[{-1, 1}, Length[xs]]}];

Show[{
  ListLinePlot[{}, PlotRange -> {{0, .5}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True],
  ListLinePlot[Select[Between[First@#, {0, .5}] &]@data,  Axes -> None]},
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {Scaled[.03], Scaled[.03]}}]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

> PS:- You can extend this by making the `Scaled` parameter a function of the data y-range above the y-axis max and the range and the y-axis.  This would automate the padding so you wouldn't have to eyeball it each time. Similarly for the data y-range below the y-axis min.

Comment: With Select you don't interpolate the data at the edges as it happens with the default ListLinePlot (but only at the vertical edges unfortunately, see the question).